# How can I convert a char array to a string in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a char array called `firstFileStream[50]`, which is being written to from an infile using fstream.

I want to convert this char array into a string called `firstFileAsString`. If I write `string firstFileAsString = firstFileStream;` it only writes the first word within the array and stops at the first space, or empty character. If I write `firstFileAsString(firstFileStream)` I get the same output.

How do I write the whole char array, so all words within it, to a string?

Here is the code to read in and write:

```
string firstInputFile = "inputText1.txt";
char firstFileStream[50];

ifstream openFileStream;
openFileStream.open(firstInputFile);

if (strlen(firstFileStream) == 0) { // If the array is empty
    cout << "First File Stream: " << endl;
    while (openFileStream.good()) { // While we haven't reached the end of the    file
        openFileStream >> firstFileStream;  
    }
    string firstFileAsString = firstFileStream;

}
```

Comment: How do you know how many characters to copy?

Comment: The input file is at a set length containing that number of characters, including whitespace

Comment: @Magis Do you mean you need to copy 50 characters, or is it some secret number?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in reading from the fstream, but you need to show some *actual* code that demonstartes the problem.

Comment: `openFileStream >> firstFileStream;` reads only the first word from the file. @zdan for the win.

Comment: Oh awesome okay, how would I go about reading the whole file then? Would I use no skip white space?

Comment: That would be one way. Another way is to use [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read), possibly in conjunction with [`gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) or [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) and [`tellg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)

Answer (score 0):

My problem, as [zdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4304/zdan) pointed out, is I was only reading the first word of the file, so instead I've used `istreambuf_iterator<char>` to assign the content directly to the string rather than the character array first. This can then be broken down into a character array, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

```
openFileStream >> firstFileStream;
```

reads only one word from the file.

A simple example of reading the whole file (at least up to the buffering capacity) looks like this:

```
openFileStream.read(firstFileStream, sizeof(firstFileStream) - 1); 
// sizeof(firstFileStream) - 1 so we have space for the string terminator
int bytesread;
if (openFileStream.eof()) // read whole file
{
    bytesread = openFileStream.gcount(); // read whatever gcount returns
}
else if (openFileStream) // no error. stopped reading before buffer overflow or end of file
{
    bytesread = sizeof(firstFileStream) - 1; //read full buffer
}    
else // file read error
{
    // handle file error here. Maybe gcount, maybe return.
}
firstFileStream[bytesread] = '\0'; // null terminate string
```